# Using M to do calculation across multiple columns in Power Query and ignore case

Tags: powerquery

I am using the M code below to search multiple columns for either the words "Pass" or "Fail".  Is there a way to make it case insensitive.  Tried to using Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase to no avail. Thanks

```
List.Count(
List.Select(
Record.ToList(_),
each _ ="Pass" or _ ="Fail")
            )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have just used

```
List.Count(
List.Select(
Record.ToList(_),
each Text.Upper(_) ="PASS" or Text.Upper(_) ="FAIL")
        )
```